# Tridion Component Link not working

Tags: sdl-tridion, dynamic-linking

We are facing a strange issue on our staging sites, after publishing the page, if there is any component link in the page then page breaks down. It discards everything from this component link in the final HTML in the browser, however, HTML seems to be correct formed in the server page. Also While previewing in CMS, I can see the complete HTML. We are using SDL web 8 , and DWT in CMS

I can see DWT code for the Component link is correct, default TBB "link resolver TBB" is also working fine as I can see correct tcdl tags in the package zip, Deployer is also working fine as I can see below correctly formed tags in final html page in the server

```
<tridion:ComponentLink pageURI="tcm:63-9966-64" componentURI="tcm:63-10289" templateURI="tcm:0-0-0" addAnchor="false" linkText="Contests" linkAttributes=" style=&#34;display:none&#34; id=&#34;select1&#34;" textOnFail="true"/>
```

But there is an issue in these links as my final output in the browser is not having anything which is below these links or even ignoring this component link itself. so Basically in the server, i can see below HTML in the JSP page

```
 <div class="rightBanner">
        <div class="rbTopBlank">&nbsp;</div>
    </div> 
    <tridion:ComponentLink pageURI="tcm:63-9966-64" componentURI="tcm:63-10289" templateURI="tcm:0-0-0" addAnchor="false" linkText="Contests" linkAttributes=" style=&#34;display:none&#34; id=&#34;select1&#34;" textOnFail="true"/>
    <img src="/en/system/images/generic/select-2m.png"  style="display:none;" id="image2"/>
    <img src="/en/system/images/generic/select-gifts.png"  style="display:none;" id="image3"/>
```

But in the browser, I can only see

```
<div class="rightBanner">
    <div class="rbTopBlank">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

So it is discarding everything after the component link. If I remove Component Links from Page in Tridion, then whole page loads correctly.

I can see cd_linking-8.1.1-1008.jar and cd_tags.tld files are present in the bin folder and seems there is nothing wrong in the dynamic link resolver as it is working in live. any clues ? Also i can see cd_dynamic.xml is having entries for each publication , for example :

```
<Publication Id="xyz"> <Host Domain="xyz.com" Port="80" Protocol="http" Path="/en" /> </Publication>
```

Is it a mandatory setting ? and What it indicates ? (i do not see this setting in live)

One more thing we found in the Application logs that's it is trying to resolved to the Parent Structure group. for example

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101214> <Included resource or file "/xyz/en/birthdays/" not found from requested resource "/xyz/en/birthdays/demoform.jsp".> 
<Jan 5, 2020, 1:32:33,97 PM GST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101019> <[ServletContext@703604789[app:xyz module:xyz path:null spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an IOException.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: [HTTP:101214]Included resource or file "/xyz/en/birthdays/" not found from requested resource "/xyz/en/birthdays/demoform.jsp".
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.NestedServletResponse.handleResourceNotFoundFromDefaultServlet(NestedServletResponse.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.NestedServletResponse.sendError(NestedServletResponse.java:130)
    at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.findSource(FileServlet.java:302)
```

Comment: Please update your question and provide a bit more details on the Tridion version and web app details use in-process or CIL?

Comment: Looks like you are using Tridion 8.1.1 and web app in-process API, Double check is there any error in your web app cd_core.log file, Try to enable logback.xml to DEBUG or TRACE to see what it's going on?

Comment: It's possible that something in the `linkAttributes` is breaking the HTML. What happens if you remove that attribute from the ComponentLink tag?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWilliams for your comments, but this link attribute is only having style and id, so it dint help after removing these. i found some errors in deployer logs, updating the description.

Comment: Can you please include more logging? A stack trace perhaps?

Comment: @Quirijn added stack trace.

Comment: Might be this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs?

Comment: It's probably a red herring, I don't think the deployer is involved in the error you are seeing. Do you see anything in the content service logs?

Comment: Hi @Quirijn we are still using old legacy architecture in web 8.5 , so only httpupload to deploy the pages , i believe pages are formed correctly in the server (i can see custom tridion tags etc) , but while rendering in browser on run time, dynamic link resolver might getting errors. i am not sure how to check log for dynamic link resolver.It is only happening in uat not in live, same page is working fine in  live with the same code deploy

Comment: In that case you can probably configure the logging of the CD api in the logback.xml in your web app.

Comment: @Quirijn i saw the logback.xml file , the logs was already configured for cd, i have just added the content delivery logs as well, if that hints something somehow –

Comment: @Quirijn We are still having old DWT Templated for this site, remaining sites are Razor Templates, is this cause any problem ?

Comment: That is unlikely. The problem is in the website, not the templates. Have you set the log level of the web application to debug? Can you share the logging? NB: the content deployer has nothing to do with it, so you can ignore that.

Comment: Thanks @Quirijn for your comments, already added teh application logs as below : "One more thing we found in the Application logs that's it is trying to resolved to the Parent Structure group. for example  <Included resource or file "/xyz/en/birthdays/" not found from requested resource "/xyz/en/birthdays/demoform.jsp".> "

Answer (score 1):

@neelesh: from stack trace it says "Can't find configuration file: [ preview_dao_bundle.xml ]"

The "preview_doa_bundle.xml" is embedded in the cd_session.jar and the "cd_webservice_preview_cartrige.xml" is embedded in the cd_preview_ambient.jar.

We would NOT find an explicit configuration in our /config/ folder. Do you have the jars mentioned above in your bin location?

Comment: yes, i have added these jars in my lib folder and restarted web logic servers, but still i can see broken html in the browser, and application logs as above. I think it is trying to find the parent directory which is the main issue.