# Dynamic link resolved to Parent Structure group

Tags: dynamic-linking, link-resolver

This relates to my previous question [Component Link not working issue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20603/tridion-component-link-not-working)

So basically Component links are not working and the final output in browser discarding everything after the component link, i can see the java custom tags related to link resolver in the server but on run time it fails to resolve those tags. We are using sdl web 8 and in CMS DWT.

in Application logs we found out that Component link is somehow getting resolved to the parent structure group, for example below is printed in logs :

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101214> <Included resource or file "/xyz/en/birthdays/" not found from requested resource "/xyz/en/birthdays/demoform.jsp".> 
<Jan 5, 2020, 1:32:33,97 PM GST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101019> <[ServletContext@703604789[app:xyz module:xyz path:null spec-version:3.1]] Servlet failed with an IOException.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: [HTTP:101214]Included resource or file "/ejunior_ae_stg/en/birthdays/" not found from requested resource "/ejunior_ae_stg/en/birthdays/demoform.jsp".
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.NestedServletResponse.handleResourceNotFoundFromDefaultServlet(NestedServletResponse.java:181)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.NestedServletResponse.sendError(NestedServletResponse.java:130)
    at weblogic.servlet.FileServlet.findSource(FileServlet.java:302)
```

Any clue ?

If i add any component link then on run time i get the broken page, although full html is present in the server. pfb, it has open divs, discarded everything as soon as it gets anchor componentLink tag in the jsp

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Neelesh: 1 quick question: are you using any ADF framework for your application.
in my knowledge these kind of error messages used to pooed up where ADF framework or dependent libraries are present.
if answer is yes please try to check if all dependent jar files and libraries has been deployed properly or not.

Also you have mentioned that java custom tags are not resolving if you can able to provide some details on those custom tags then that will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @soumava for your comments, These are the tags which are present in jsp file on the server and configured in cd_tags.tld file, and dynaic reolver know them. for example "componentLink" , so these are formed correctly in the final jsp along with other html , but when i browse my page run time , then i get broken page, when i see the page source i do not see any html which i added after component link , i am adding a screenshot for the same. please see the linked question once. Thanks for you help.